# Возможно ли передать response в конструктор?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли передать response в конструктор? new PaginationQuestion(1, 12, 'withTags', response.items[i].id)

```
  + '<div class="mb-1" onclick="new PaginationQuestion(1, 12, \'withTags\', ).setQuestions()">'
            + response.items[i].name
            + '</div>'
            + '<span id="spanX">'
```

```
'<span  class="item-multiplier-count" id="Tag-countId">'+ response.items[i].id + '</span>'
+ '<div class="mb-1" onclick="new PaginationQuestion(1, 12, \'withTags\', document.getElementById(\'Tag-countId\').value).setQuestions()">'
```

Comment: в случае собирания строки передать объект невозможно. Можно только вставить  конкретные значения типа строк чисел и т.д. Если нужен именно объект, стоит вместо inline обработчика добавлять обработчик с помощью `js` через свойство `onclick` либо метод `.addEventListener`

Comment: Спасибо, вот таким способом можно?  добавил к вопросу (не получается получить значение, через getElementById )

Comment: убери `-` из `id`. В этом случае можешь сразу `response.items[i].id` в строку встраивать а не пытаться взять из элемента, в данном случае тем более надо было использовать `textContent` а не `value`. Невозможно именно объект передать, так как в текущем виде у тебя строка или число - то вполне можно просто встроить в собираемую строку

Comment: Оу:) с `textContent` проходит, спасибо большое!

Comment: В этом случае можешь сразу response.items[i].id в строку встраивать (не совсем понял как это)

Comment: точно так же как ты делаешь тут `'<span  class="item-multiplier-count" id="Tag-countId">'+ response.items[i].id + '</span>'` ты встраиваешь в строку значение `response.items[i].id` - вставляй его сразу в нужное место и `document.getElementById(\'Tag-countId\').value` уже не нужен

Comment: response.items[i].id нужен в конструкторе, туда его не получается вставить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118620/discussion-between-grundy-and-roman).